# Leetcode 413: Arithmetic slices Python

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

Hi I'm trying to solve Leetcode 413: Arithmetic slices. I'm trying to start with a brute force recursive solution.

```py
 def numberOfArithmeticSlices(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
      def slices(nums: List[int], i: int):
          if (i < 2):
              return 0
          if nums[i] - nums[i-1] == nums[i-1] - nums[i-2]:
              return 1 + slices(nums, i -1)
          else:
              return slices(nums, i-1)
        if len(nums) < 3:
            return 0
        return slices(nums, len(nums)-1)
```

This doesn't work for the test case `[1,2,3,4]` (it returns 2 instead of 3). In my head I know it doesn't work because when the function is called, `1 + slices([1,2,3], 2)` returns 2. How can I fix my code to get the arithmetic slice coming from the entire array `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: *"This doesn't work for the test case [1,2,3,4] (it returns 2 instead of 3)"* Hum, if you say so. Without context it's hard to understand what problem it is that you're trying to solve?

Comment: so from reading my code, it will return `1 + slices([1,2,3], 2)`. `slices([1,2,3], 2)` will return 1. Therefore my code doesn't account for the original array being an arithmetic slice (`[1,2,3,4]`) and I'm wondering how I can fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving this problem you have to take two steps.

1. First you have to find all possible contiguous sub-arrays
2. You have to check them, if they are arithmetic slices.

An understandable solution which is not memory and time efficient is as below:

```
def numberOfArithmeticSlices(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    if len(nums) <= 2:
        return 0
    sub_arrays = self.contiguous_subarray(nums)  # type List[List[int]]  all contiguous sub arrays with length 3 or more
    count = 0
    for subset in sub_arrays:
        count = count + self.is_arithmetic_subset(subset)
    return count

@staticmethod
def is_arithmetic_subset(subset):
    if len(subset) <= 2:
        return 0
    diff = subset[1] - subset[0]
    for i in range(2, len(subset)):
        if subset[i] - subset[i - 1] != diff:
            return 0
    return 1

@staticmethod
def contiguous_subarray(nums):
    return [nums[i:i + j] for i in range(0, len(nums)) for j in range(3, len(nums) - i + 1)]
```

But a solution that is little more harder to grasp but is memory and time efficient is as bellow(You could still replace the recursive call with a loop and I think you would get better results doing so):

```
def numberOfArithmeticSlices(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    array_len = len(nums)
    if array_len <= 2:
        return 0
    count = self.numberOfArithmeticSlices(nums[:array_len - 1])
    diff = nums[array_len - 1] - nums[array_len - 2]
    for i in range(2, array_len):
        if nums[array_len - i ] - nums[array_len - i - 1] == diff:
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    return count
```

Comment: so I notice in your recursive solution you don't return count until the end. I'm unsure if that's the reason yours works and my recursive solution doesn't count the original array. In what situations can I return early from a recursive call vs. only return at the end like your solution?

Comment: In fact I return early, look at the `break`. You can return the count in `else:` instead of break.

Comment: gotcha, does my code undercount the number of slices because I never return the stack to a state that has the original array? whereas in your code after count is returned from the calls with the smaller version of the array, it continues processing the original array?

Comment: @VictorCui exactly. It is not 1 + slice(n -1). You have to consider all possible ways for you last item.